# Django user accounts, extending accounts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to extend Django's user-accounts Account model to add to it a set of additional fields. The thing is that "Account" objects have a set of methods that check some parameters and I would like to re-use all that code. Therefore, the first thing that comes to my mind is to extend the Account class with my own class:

```
class snAccount(Account):

    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, related_name="sn_account", verbose_name=_("snAccount"))

    # Extra fields
    organization = models.CharField(_("language"), ...,  )    
    country = CountryField()

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, request=None, **kwargs):
        create_email = kwargs.pop("create_email", True)
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        acc = Account.create(request, user=user, create_email=create_email)
        x_account = cls(**kwargs)
        #x_account.user = request.user
        x_account.save()
        return x_account
```

The problem is that every time I want to save this "extended" Account class, I get the following exception:

```
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

If I add the user field directly to the extended account (uncommenting the line "#x_account.user = request.user" i get the following error:

```
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")
```

I thought that this field will be directly inherited from the Account model no explicit declaration of that Field is made. What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way of doing it or would I better create a model that does not extend the Account class but still links to it through a ForeignKey field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this is well documented in the Django under [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user).

Comment: The link that you provide only contains documentation about how to directly extend the User model from django.contrib.auth, which is good; but my question was about how to extend the django-user-accounts model, that already extends the django.contrib.auth one in the way that your link estates.

Comment: In the end, I think that I will follow the model defined in that link since it might be the best solution up to now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when subclassing a model, django creates a `*_ptr` field in your new model that points at the base model. When creating a new instance of your model, both your model with your attributes and the base model with base attributes are created.

In this case, if you removed the `Account.create(...)` line, django would create both `snAccount` with your custom fields, and `Account` with all the base fields filled in, and link them together.